# cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview and I'm getting navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc, getusermedia, crosswalk

I am developing an ionic WebRTC app using `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` and I'm getting navigator.getUserMedia is not a function when running on the android device any idea why?

```js
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true},
        function(stream){
            let vid = document.getElementById('my-video');

            if(vid)
            {
                vid.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(stream));
            } else {
                alert("err geting div");
            }
            //this.localStream = stream;
          
        }, function(){ alert("err");}
    );
```

```html
    <video id="my-video" muted="true" autoplay="" src=""></video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by reinstalling cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview plugin